# How to change server certificate of HTTPS listener under Glassfish 2.1.1?

Tags: https, glassfish, certificate, keystore

I have a preinstalled Glassfish domain, and I want to change the server certificate and private key of the https listener. How can I do that? Which file in config directory contains that key-pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details on how to accomplish those tasks is in the [admin guide, chapter 9](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19159-01/819-3671/ablnk/index.html).